# How to save a model field having many to many realtionship with another model so that it will update the value automatically on another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I am having a model name 'tag' which has field name talent which has many to many relationship field with model name 'talent'. now I want to update the talent field and save it and it should update the talent model's tag field. I'm new in django. Please help me to find the solution for it.

here's the code:
**tag.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from fotoleybend.mixin import (
IsActiveAndVerifiedMixin,
PrimaryKeyMixin,
TimeStampMixin,
)
from talent.models.talent import Talent


class Tag(PrimaryKeyMixin, TimeStampMixin, IsActiveAndVerifiedMixin):
"""Tag model"""

tag = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=105, db_index=True)
talents = models.ManyToManyField(
    "talent.Talent",
    blank=True,
    verbose_name=_("Tag Talents"),
    related_name="tag_talents",
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["tag"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag
```

**talent.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from fotoleybend.mixin import (
IsActiveAndVerifiedMixin,
PrimaryKeyMixin,
TimeStampMixin,
)


class Talent(PrimaryKeyMixin, TimeStampMixin, IsActiveAndVerifiedMixin):
"""Talent model"""

talent = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=155, db_index=True)
is_primary = models.BooleanField(
    verbose_name=_("Primary"), default=True, db_index=True
)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(
    "talent.Tag",
    blank=True,
    verbose_name=_("Talent Tags"),
    related_name="talent_tags",
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["talent", "is_primary"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.talent
```

Answer (score 0):

When performing operation with set or add on ManyToManyFields, Django will not update the nested objects, instead it will update the "through" table that keeps the M2M relationship between your two models, which by is using only ids. So what it does is update any ids in this table so it follows your dataset.

If you want to update a specific tag from a Talent (or the other way around), what you could do is simply save directly the wanted model:

```
tag1 = Tag.objects.create(tag='tag1')
tag2 = Tag.objects.create(tag='anothertag')
talent = Talent.objects.create(talent='flying')
tag1.tag = "modified tag1"
tag2.tag = "modified tag2"
# Setting tags, but unsaved
talent.tags.set([tag1, tag2])
talent.tags.all()
<QuerySet [<Tag: anothertag>, <Tag: tag1>]>
# Saving the tag before
talent.tags.all()
tag2.save()
<QuerySet [<Tag: modified tag2>, <Tag: tag1>]>
```